# awk - Find duplicate entries in 2 columns, keep 1 duplicate and unique entries

Tags: unix, awk, solaris

I need to find a duplicate entry in 2 different columns and keep only one of the duplicate and all unique entries. For me if A123 is in the first column and it show up later in the second column it's a duplicate. I also know for sure that A123 will always be paired to B123 by either being A123,B123 or B123,A123. I only need to keep one and it doesn't matter which one it is.

Ex: My input file would contain:
A123,B123
A234,B234
C123,D123
B123,A123
B234,A234

I'd like the output to be:
A123,B123
A234,B234
C123,D123

The best I can do is to extract the unique entries with :

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{x[$1]++;next}; !x[$2]' file1 file1
```

or get only the duplicates with

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{x[$1]++;next}; x[$2]' file1 file1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shorter!

First print if the element is not yet present in the array. Then add the first field to the array. Only one run over the inputfile is necessary:

```
awk -F, '!x[$2];{x[$1]++}' file1
```

Comment: Working great! Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware it only works due to your unique requirement that every $2 is paired to a specific $1. It wouldn't work for the general case of finding unique entries across a pair of fields since it never records having seen a $2 nor would it work for unique combinations of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner works for your example:

```
awk -F, '!($2 in a){a[$1]=$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

Comment: Longer and gives me slightly better idea how awk works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The conventional, idiomatic awk solution:

```
$ awk -F, '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 : $2]++' file
A123,B123
A234,B234
C123,D123
```

By convention we always use `seen` (rather than `x` or anything else) as the array name when it represents a set where you want to check if it's index has been seen before, and using a ternary expression to produce the largest of the possible key values as the index ensures the order they appear in the input doesn't matter.

The above doesn't care about your unique situation where every `$2` is paired to a specific `$1` - it simply prints unique individual occurrences across a pair of fields. If you wanted it to work on the pair of fields combined (and assuming you have more fields so just using `$0` as the index wouldn't work) that'd be:

```
awk -F, '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
```